# Getting Twitter characters count

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, twitter

I have a program, it is an editor for Twitter tweets, it's counting the text to make it less than 280 character as twitter restriction.

I use for that utf8 property like this:

```
var str = "℞"
let r = str.utf8.count
```

The result = 3

This symbol (℞) and more like it takes only 2 character in twitter counter but the result in this code gave me 3, so i can't give the user the exact character count!

How can I get the correct count: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Counting characters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/counting-characters.html)

> Tweet length is measured by the number of codepoints in the NFC
>   normalized version of the text.

In Swift, you can get the NFC normalized form through `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`, and the number of codepoints by `unicodeScalars.count`.

So, the right code in Swift should be like this:

```
var str = "℞"
let r = str.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.unicodeScalars.count
print(r) //->1
```

The code above shows consistent result with some character counters on the web, I do not understand why you get `2` for `℞`.

---

(Thanks to Rakesha Shastri.)
I believe the code above correctly implements the specification described in the documentation I linked above.

But it is reported that the actual Twitter does not work exactly as in the doc. (Sorry, I do not tweet myself.) We may need to guess or find another reliable source to make it fit for the actual Twitter.

---

I tried the official library [text Tweet parsing library](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-text.html), but it shows the same result as my code.

```
let len = TwitterText.tweetLength(str)
print(len) //->1
```

(Though, the code of `TwitterText.tweetLength(_:)` is far more complex, as it handles [t.co links](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/tco.html). So, when some URLs are included in the text, it generates different output than my code.)

---

(**UPDATE**)

I'm not sure as the referred twitter apps are not open-source, but I guess they are showing the *weighted length* described in the *text Tweet parsing library* page linked above.

You may need to write something like this with importing the library using pod.

```
let config = TwitterTextConfiguration(fromJSONResource: kTwitterTextParserConfigurationV2)
let parser = TwitterTextParser(configuration: config)
let result = parser.parseTweet(str)
print(result.weightedLength) //->2
```

Comment: I read the same document and thought this was the solution. But if you go to twitter and type the character, it counts it as 2, not 1.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, thanks. That may happen some actual implementations do more than documented. I add note on it.

Comment: This symbol take 2 characters in Twitter App in iphone also in Tweetbot App !!

Comment: @user2713544, thank you. I'm wandering around on the web, since Rakesha Shastri told me actual Twitter shows 2 for your example. But sorry, I could not found any clue till now.

Comment: If you are really sure you have included the framework into **Linked Libraries and Frameworks** and got that error, I cannot tell you how to fix it. You may need to include all source files and resource files into your project.

Comment: Thank you I used the library linked above and it is solved my problem

Comment: You're right that Twitter's docs are wrong. They claim to count *Unicode code points*, but really count *UTF-16 code units*. (This is the way that string lengths are measured in JavaScript and C#, by the way; I suspect that on their backend they're measuring string lengths in a language that measures string lengths in UTF-16 code units and whoever wrote the docs has no idea that these aren't the same thing as Unicode code points.) I'm not a Swift dev so not sure how best to measure a string's UTF-16 code unit length in Swift; I'll leave that bit to you.

Comment: BTW, since there doesn't seem to be an official way to report bugs that I can find, I signed up for a Twitter account and Tweeted at @TwitterSupport about this docs bug: https://twitter.com/XplodingCabbage/status/1074355570512142336. We'll see if anything comes of it.