# Loop through Unicode string as character

Tags: c++, string, unicode, string-length

With the following string, the size is incorrectly output. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
string str = " ██████";
cout << str.size();
// outputs 19 rather than 7
```

I'm trying to loop through `str` character by character so I can read it into into a `vector<string>` which should have a size of 7, but I can't do this since the above code outputs 19.

Comment: You may use a `wstring` not a `string`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that won't work if `wstring` uses UTF-16 and the characters are outside the BMP. It won't also work for many characters with diacritics, since [some are precomposed and some can be combined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character):  Å = U+00C5 or U+0041 plus U+030A and without proper normalization calling `length` may return 1 or 2 and not a consistent number that one expects

Comment: @phuclv just have a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I already saw that yesterday, and it's incorrect if what the OP wants is the number of characters

Comment: @ToasterFrogs you need to explain why you expect it to `have a size of 6`. Are you interested in the **number of visible characters**? That's not what developers want in most situations. And even in that case then you must also choose one normalization, since Å can result in 1 or 2 characters depending on the viewpoint, and ‍‍‍  actually consists of 7 characters under the hood. Are you only interested in strings with █ or with any other Unicode characters?

Comment: @phuclv I mistyped. I am looking for an output of 7 - the post has been edited. I am interested in using other Unicode characters such as `▖`, `▒`, `◢`, and possibly other box drawing characters. I am looking for the number of characters in the string - in the cases you mentioned, I would like `1` to be returned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

The `size()` and `length()` members of [`basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) returns the size in *units* of the underlying string, **not** the ***number of visible characters***. To get the expected number:

- Use UTF-16 with `u` prefix for very simple strings that contain no non-BMP, no [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) and no [joining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)
- Use UTF-32 with `U` prefix for very simple strings that don't contain any combining or joining characters
- Normalize the string and count for arbitrary Unicode strings

---

`" ██████"` is a space followed by a series of 6 [U+2588](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm) characters. Your compiler seems to be using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for `std::string`. UTF-8 is a [variable-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding) and many letters are encoded using multiple bytes (because obviously you can't encode more than 256 characters with just one byte). In UTF-8 code points between U+0800 and U+FFFF are encoded by 3 bytes. Therefore the length of the the string in UTF-8 is **1 + 6*3 = 19** bytes.

You can check with any Unicode converter like [this one](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) and see that the string is encoded as `20 E2 96 88 E2 96 88 E2 96 88 E2 96 88 E2 96 88 E2 96 88` in UTF-8, and you can also loop through each byte of your string to check

If you want the **total number of *visible* characters** in the string then it's a lot trickier and **churill's solution doesn't work**. Read the example in [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/counting-characters)

> If you use anything beyond the most basic letters, numbers, and punctuation the situation gets more confusing. While many people use multi-byte Kanji characters to exemplify these issues, Twitter has found that accented vowels cause the most confusion because English speakers simply expect them to work. Take the following example: the word “café”. It turns out there are two byte sequences that look exactly the same, but use a different number of bytes:
>
> ```
> café  0x63 0x61 0x66 0xC3 0xA9        Using the “é” character, called the “composed character”.
> café  0x63 0x61 0x66 0x65 0xCC 0x81   Using the combining diacritical, which overlaps the “e”
> ```

You need a Unicode library like [ICU](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu) to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) the string and count. Twitter for example uses [Normalization Form C](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

## Edit:

Since you're only interested in box-drawing characters which doesn't seem to lie outside the BMP and don't contain any combining characters, UTF-16 and UTF-32 will work. Like `std::string`, `std::wstring` is also a `basic_string` and doesn't have a mandatory encoding. In most implementations it's often either UTF-16 (Windows) or UTF-32 (*nix) so you may use it, but it's unreliable and depends on source code encoding. The better way is to use `std::u16string` (`std::basic_string<char16_t>`) and `std::u32string` (`std::basic_string<char32_t>`). They'll work regardless of system and encoding of the source file

```
std::wstring wstr     = L" ██████";
std::u16string u16str = u" ██████";
std::u32string u32str = U" ██████";
std::cout << str.size();    // may work, returns the number of wchar_t characters
std::cout << u16str.size(); // always returns the number of UTF-16 code units
std::cout << u32str.size(); // always returns the number of UTF-32 code units
```

In case you're interested in how to work out on that for all Unicode characters continue reading below

> The “café” issue mentioned above raises the question of how you count the characters in the Tweet string “café”. To the human eye the length is clearly four characters. Depending on how the data is represented this could be either five or six UTF-8 bytes. Twitter does not want to penalize a user for the fact we use UTF-8 or for the fact that the API client in question used the longer representation. Therefore, Twitter does count “café” as four characters, no matter which representation is sent.
>
> [...]
>
> Twitter counts the length of a Tweet using the Normalization Form C (NFC) version of the text. This type of normalization favors the use of a fully combined character (0xC3 0xA9 from the café example) over the long-form version (0x65 0xCC 0x81). Twitter also counts the number of codepoints in the text rather than UTF-8 bytes. The 0xC3 0xA9 from the café example is one codepoint (U+00E9) that is encoded as two bytes in UTF-8, whereas 0x65 0xCC 0x81 is two codepoints encoded as three bytes
>
> [Twitter - Counting characters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/counting-characters)

See also

- [When "Zoë" !== "Zoë". Or why you need to normalize Unicode strings](https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html)
- [Getting Twitter characters count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52688683/995714)
- [Why is the length of this string longer than the number of characters in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26975736/995714)

Comment: Did you make mistake "In most implementations it's often either UTF-16 (Windows) or UTF-16 (*nix)"? std::wstring and wchar_t are 32 bit in gcc and maybe in clang by default at least in *nix.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` only contains 1 byte long chars (usually 8 bit, contains UTF-8 char), you need `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` to achieve what you want:

```
std::wstring str = L" ██████";
std::cout << str.size();
```

Allthough this prints 7 (one space and 6 unicode chars). Notice the L before the string literal, so it will be interpreted as a wide string.

Comment: technically `char` isn't required to be 8-bit long. Some platforms may have longer `char`

Comment: @churill `std::string` knows nothing about UTF-8, and won't "usually" hold UTF-8 unless you actually make it hold UTF-8. Whether UTF-8 is used really depends on the platform being used, the compiler settings, the encoding of the source file, etc. At the very least, if you want a literal in UTF-8, use the `u8` prefix: `string str = u8" ██████";` but the other factors I mentioned still play into it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, I'm bad at finding the right terminology, feel free to edit it :)

Comment: as commented above, this returns the **number of UTF-16** (or UTF-32 depending on implementation) **code units** and not the *number of characters in the string* (if that's what the OP wants, since currently it's still unclear) so it definitely won't work for strings like `"‍Å"` (it'll return 9 for UTF-16 and 6 for UTF-32)